# Qual destas opções é melhor e mais rápido para um INSERT no banco?

Tags: x++

Em relação a performance, qual destes é o "melhor" e mais rápido ?

Existe alguma situação em que não devemos utilizar algum deles ou até mesmo utilizar somente um deles ? Pois afinal, todos cumprem o mesmo papel.

- RecordInsertList
- insert_recordset
- UnitOfWork

**RecordInsertList**

```
RecordInsertList insertList = new RecordInsertList(tableNum(TableExample));
// Alguma lógica de négocio...

insertList.add(buffer1);
insertList.add(buffer2);
insertList.add(buffer3);

insertList.insertDataBase();
```

**insert_recordset**

```
insert_recordset buffer (myNum, mySum)
select myNum, sum(myValue) from outroBuffer
    group by myNum 
    where outroBuffer.myNum == 100;
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork();

// Alguma lógica de negócio ...
uow.insertOnSaveChanges(buffer1);
uow.insertOnSaveChanges(buffer2);
uow.insertOnSaveChanges(buffer3);
uow.saveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, realizei alguns testes e cheguei a uma conclusão.

**Segue o detalhamento:**

- *"Qual destas opções é melhor e mais rápido ..."*

> Mais rápido

A forma mais rápida para inserção no banco é implementando com o `Insert_RecordSet`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Legenda:**

- Insert Regular -> `buffer.insert()`
- Insert List -> `RecordInsertList`
- Insert UOW -> `UnitOfWork`
- Insert_recordSet -> `Insert_RecordSet`

**Código útilizado nos testes**

```
class PerformanceTestes_COL 
{   
    MuBuffer    buffer;
    int         rows;
    int         timeStart;
    int         timeEnd;
    int         i;
    str         timeConsumed; 
}

private void process() {
    rows = 10000;

    this.InsertTest();
    this.RecordInsertListTest();
    this.UOWTest();
    this.insertRecordSetTest(); 
}

private void InsertTest() {
    buffer.clear();

    timeStart = timeNow();

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        buffer.InventSiteId             = "001";
        buffer.ItemId                   = "161634";
        buffer.RetailVariantId          = "53458";

        buffer.insert();
    }

    timeEnd = timeNow();

    timeConsumed = timeConsumed(timeStart, timeEnd);
    info(strFmt("Insert Regular (%1) rows - time: %2", rows, timeConsumed)); 
}

private void RecordInsertListTest() {
    RecordInsertList    list = new RecordInsertList(tableNum(MixItemCovCopy_TestPerformance_COL));
    ;

    buffer.clear();

    timeStart = timeNow();

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        buffer.InventSiteId             = "002";
        buffer.ItemId                   = "161634";
        buffer.RetailVariantId          = "53458";

        list.add(buffer);
    }

    list.insertDatabase();

    timeEnd = timeNow();

    timeConsumed = timeConsumed(timeStart, timeEnd);
    info(strFmt("Insert List (%1) rows - time: %2", rows, timeConsumed)); 
}

private void UOWTest() {
    UnitofWork      uow = new UnitofWork();
    ;

    buffer.clear();

    timeStart = timeNow();

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        buffer.InventSiteId             = "003";
        buffer.ItemId                   = "161634";
        buffer.RetailVariantId          = "53458";

        uow.insertonSaveChanges(buffer);
    }

    uow.saveChanges();

    timeEnd = timeNow();

    timeConsumed = timeConsumed(timeStart, timeEnd);
    info(strFmt("Insert UOW (%1) rows - time: %2", rows, timeConsumed)); 
}

private void insertRecordSetTest() {
    // Buffer 2 contém 10000 registros
    Buffer2      buffer2;
    ;

    buffer.clear();

    timeStart = timeNow();

    insert_recordset buffer (InventSiteId, ItemId, RetailVariantId)
    select InventSiteId, ItemId, RetailVariantId from buffer2;

    timeEnd = timeNow();

    timeConsumed = timeConsumed(timeStart, timeEnd);
    info(strFmt("Insert_recordSet (%1) rows - time: %2", rows, timeConsumed)); 
}
```

---

> Melhor

A melhor forma para inserção no banco é .. **depende**! Pois cada caso pode ser tratado de forma diferente onde não será possível utilizar uma das possibilidades que citei na reposta.

**Por exemplo:** Se uma customização exigir uma tratativa nos dados com alguns IF's e lógica de negócio já não será possível utilizar o `Insert_RecordSet` pois mesmo este sendo o *mais rápido*, esta forma de inserção não é muito maleável de se tratar os registros antes ou no momento do insert.

Sabendo isto, devemos avaliar a customização em que iremos trabalhar e codificar para implementar e tratar os dados de acordo com as melhores práticas da **Microsoft**. Caso esta exigir um mapeamento apropriado para buffers diferentes é conveniente implementar com o `UnitOfWork`. Se for necessário apenas uma lógica de negócio durante a iteração de uma `query` sem dúvidas que devemos utilizar `RecordInsertList` *(2° mais rápido)* e não tratar com um simples `buffer.insert()`, isto trará um grande ganho no processamento dos dados.

Minha recomendação é que não utilize `buffer.insert()` a não ser que a customização seja muito simplória ou que se esgote todas as demais opções de inserção, acredite, seu servidor irá te agradecer!

Links úteis:
[Insert](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/insert-table-method) - 
[RecordInsertList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics/ax-2012/system-classes/gg923747(v=ax.60)) - 
[UnitOfWork](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/how-to-use-the-unitofwork-class-to-manage-database-transactions) - 
[Insert_RecordSet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/insert-recordset)

Espero ter ajudado e esclarecido o assunto.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá, abaixo vou tentar explicar:

-insert_recordset: copia os dados de uma ou mais tabela diretamente para uma tabela de destino, sendo assim, só faz uma viagem do servidor. Isso acaba sendo mais rápido do que uma inserção de valores na matriz (mas a inserção apesar de ser mais "demorada" são mais maleáveis na manipulação dos dados).

-recordInsertList: serve como um buffer, e o que seria buffer? É uma região da memoria física que é utilizada para armazenar de maneira temporária algum tipo de dado. O recordInsertList está mais para uma classe que trabalha com os mais variados métodos, sendo assim possui mais variedades, como por exemplo, permitir a inserção de mais de um registro no banco de dados por vez, fazendo com que a comunicação entre a aplicação e o banco seja menor.

Comment: Certo, eu já entendo superficialmente estes processos. Porém os 3 processos (`RecorInsertList`, `insert_recordset` e `UnitOfWork`) não fazem somente uma viagem ao servidor ? O insert_recordset ok, faz uma viagem ao servidor, já os métodos `insertDataBase()` do `RecordInsertList` e o `saveChanges()` do `UnitOfWork` também não se comportam da mesma forma ?